# How to connect postgresql database with java server faces

Tags: database, postgresql, jsf

Currently I'm an ubuntu user and I have tomcat on that I'm tryıng to connect my postgre sql database with my java server faces. I also downloaded the postgresql java database connector too but I can't handle that.

Comment: NetBeans has nothing to do with it. Define 'can't handle'. Do you know about JDBC?

Comment: yes ı used ojdbc for oracle connectıon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this step by step. Break it up into pieces, deal with each piece separately.

PostgreSQL has nothing to do with Java Server Faces. In fact, JSF2 has nothing to do with data sources at all, it justs EL to do string substitutions or uses custom component classes. The EL expressions might be `@Named` beans with data source injection; similarly, custom component classes might request injected data sources. Injection can be done using JNDI's own injection, EJB injection for EJB3s, or CDI injection for CDI beans. Yes, that's horribly complicated, but it's how JSF2 works.

You must:

- Install the pgJDBC driver in Tomcat like any other JDBC driver
- Set up a Tomcat connection pool like any other JDBC connection pool
- ... and then use it like any other JDBC data source
- Create beans (CDI beans, JSF2 beans, or EJBs) that use your data source via injection
- Create JSF2 pages that use the named beans via EL expressions

The only PostgreSQL specific parts are the details of the SQL query text, and the JDBC connection parameters.

So you really need to [start with the basic documentation and tutorials that explain how to install JDBC drivers, set up connection pools, etc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html). Or if you need a JNDI DataSource, see [the docs for that](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html). You'll also need to study some basic JSF2 tutorials.